# Prolog function to create multiplication tables

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a prolog function that gets a small multiplication table based on the first value pased to the function.

My code is currently as follows:

```
mult(n, [[[n, 1], n*1], [[n,2], n*2], [[n,3], n*3]]).
```

So for example I would like a query such as:

```
?- mult(5, R).
```

To display something like:

```
R = [[[5,1],5], [[5,2],10], [[5,3], 15]]
```

However, currently this query only returns `false`, how could I fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, like this. The capital letters for variable names are mandatory.

```
mult(N, [[[N, 1], N1], [[N,2], N2], [[N,3], N3]]) :-
    N1 is 1*N,
    N2 is 2*N,
    N3 is 3*N.
```

or maybe:

```
mult(N, R) :-
    numlist(1, 3, M),
    maplist(x(N), M, R).

x(N, M, [[N, M], P]) :-
    P is N * M.
```

You could also abuse `findall` to get the same result in a one-liner.

```
?- findall([[5,X],P], ( between(1, 3, X), P is 5*X ), R).
R = [[[5, 1], 5], [[5, 2], 10], [[5, 3], 15]].
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mulTable(N,End):-
    mulTable(N,1,End).
mulTable(_N,Start,End):-
    Start > End.
mulTable(N,Counter,End):-
    Counter =< End,
    write(N),
    write('X'),
    write(Counter),
    write('='),
    Mul is N*Counter,
    write(Mul),
    nl,
    NewCounter is Counter +1,
    mulTable(N,NewCounter,End).
```